# JSONException: No value for error

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I'm getting the following error:

```
JSONException: No value for error
```

On my logs (link to see a screenshot of my logs: https://i.stack.imgur.com/45eeF.png) in Android Studio it says that the cause is because of this line of code:

```
boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
```

Also the cause is because of this line of code:

```
AppConfig.URL_LOGIN, new Response.Listener<String>() {
```

When I had send the request to my server (so that I can log in into my app). I can see that it went with succes. I have logged it on server here is the output:

```
output user
{ _id: 5650e78597f6e98413a737d4,
  name: 'b',
  email: 'b@hotmail.com',
  hashed_password: 'r+rDSXpJtFl7rXzUNyNbhAwgBSNq5uk2khARiyHyqUzTNF8dkXbUhRhErvMfsUMpUxg89zFWw57uOlI7O006aw==',
  salt: 'gzoxOSNZkTvOHyl9xzKZAg==',
  username: 'b',
  __v: 0,
  provider: 'local',
  roles: [ 'authenticated' ] }
end output user
POST /api/login 200 355 - 54.181 ms
```

On the other hand the response from the server looks different. I have logged it on my app here is the output:

```
11-22 19:34:30.374 3668-3668/? I/System.out: output response
11-22 19:34:30.375 3668-3668/? I/System.out: {"token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.JTdCJTIyX2lkJTIyOiUyMjU2NTBlNzg1OTdmNmU5ODQxM2E3MzdkNCUyMiwlMjJuYW1lJTIyOiUyMmIlMjIsJTIyZW1haWwlMjI6JTIyYkBob3RtYWlsLmNvbSUyMiwlMjJ1c2VybmFtZSUyMjolMjJiJTIyLCUyMl9fdiUyMjowLCUyMnByb3ZpZGVyJTIyOiUyMmxvY2FsJTIyLCUyMnJvbGVzJTIyOiU1QiUyMmF1dGhlbnRpY2F0ZWQlMjIlNUQlN0Q.eXM6a4dUMDMv2feQpzbgi0q355jbINXI5ErlP_jKNk0","redirect":"/"}
11-22 19:34:30.375 3668-3668/? I/System.out: end output response
```

I'm posting my method through a link, because the method is too big to post it here. In the link below you can see my method:

http://pastebin.com/ix9YpkKa

Comment: It means there is no key named "error" in your response. As you can see, your response contains two keys... "token" and "redirect"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error clearly says,

```
JSONException: No value for error
```

That means it was not able to find the `error` key. In your code,

```
                System.out.println("output response");
                System.out.println(response);
                System.out.println("end output response");
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
```

The response that you get from the server

```
{"token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.JTdCJTIyX2lkJTIyOiUyMjU2NTBlNzg1OTdmNmU5ODQxM2E3MzdkNCUyMiwlMjJuYW1lJTIyOiUyMmIlMjIsJTIyZW1haWwlMjI6JTIyYkBob3RtYWlsLmNvbSUyMiwlMjJ1c2VybmFtZSUyMjolMjJiJTIyLCUyMl9fdiUyMjowLCUyMnByb3ZpZGVyJTIyOiUyMmxvY2FsJTIyLCUyMnJvbGVzJTIyOiU1QiUyMmF1dGhlbnRpY2F0ZWQlMjIlNUQlN0Q.eXM6a4dUMDMv2feQpzbgi0q355jbINXI5ErlP_jKNk0","redirect":"/"}
```

Has only 2 keys. One is the `token` and the other is `redirect`. You are trying to find the `error` in this in the following line and hence its crashing.

```
boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
```

To fix the above, you can check if the `JSONObject` contains the `error` key before fetching its value. It'd be something like

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
if(jObj.contains("error")){
    boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
}
```

Comment: I also got another tiny question, is it the right way to do it like this? Link to code:
http://pastebin.com/CQJWsdxV